# Display missing rows (oracle, sql)

Tags: sql, oracle, replace, oracle12c, contains

I have run below select:

```
select replace(replace(id,'[',''),']','') as ID from tableA where COL1= 'TEST';
```

It returns **15 rows**.

```
example of id:

1abc
3def
9abc
..
..
..
14abc
```

Then I'm looking this ID into other table:

```
select col1, col3 from tableB where 
      id in (select replace(replace(id,'[',''),']','') from tableA where COL1= 'TEST');
```

It returns **12 rows.**

```
1abc   city1
2def   city2
5abc   city2
..     ..
12abc  city3
```

*How to display missing 3 rows?*

Comment: Add some sample table data that illustrates the problem - as formatted text, not images. Feel free to minimize, perhaps 4 and 3 rows instead of 15 and 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that there aren't actually any missing rows, but rather that 3 of the 15 rows returned by the first query are actually duplicate `id` values.

To see how this might work, consider that the first query returned the following 5 `id` values (for the sake of simplicity):

```
1
1
1
2
2
```

There are in fact 5 `id` values, but only 2 are actually unique.  Then, the following `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE id IN (1, 1, 1, 2, 2)
```

is equivalent to just saying:

```
WHERE id IN (1, 2)
```

Another possibility to this might be that `tableB` just does not contain every `id` returned by the first query.

To find the missing rows, here is one way:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(id, '[', ''), ']', '') AS ID
    FROM tableA
    WHERE COL1= 'TEST'
)

SELECT a.ID
FROM cte a
LEFT JOIN tableB b
    ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE b.ID IS NULL;
```

Comment: my first query returns unique, from second query I can got less, this is ok. but how to find which are not founded?

Comment: @4est One approach is to use an anti-join, q.v. my updated answer.